# i am not able to query the sub document in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i am not able to query results in this query,
i want result based on detail.type (like fetch record where detail.type="one") and fetch only first 10 records in detail.numbers array

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a27b609e101b6092b4ebf91"),
            "city" : "Mumbai",
            "detail" : [
                {
                    "type" : "One",
                    "name" : "Some name",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a27b609e101b6092b4ebf92"),
                    "numbers" : [
                        "72598xxx78",
                        "81301xxx88",
                        "83302xxx30",
                        "84309xxx43",
                        "85309xxx77",
                        "86309xxx61",
                        "87270xxx88",
                        "85272xxx36",
                        "88272xxx23",
                        "85276xxx01"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Some name",
                    "type" : "two",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a28e954d4f5a30527d92a32"),
                    "contact" : [
                        "72598xxx78",
                        "81301xxx88",
                        "83302xxx30",
                        "84309xxx43",
                        "85309xxx77",
                        "86309xxx61",
                        "87270xxx88",
                        "85272xxx36",
                        "88272xxx23",
                        "85276xxx01"
                    ]
                },
    ]
    }
```

Comment: How do you query your search?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB facilitates querying over array elements using **$elemMatch** operator.

According to description as mentioned into above question as a solution to it please try executing following MongoDB query to fetch required data from MongoDB collection.

```
db.collection.find({
    detail: {
        $elemMatch: {
            type: 'One'
        }
    }
}, {
    _id: 1,
    city: 1,
    'detail.$': 1
})
```

Comment: its is giving one array of type one, but i can have multiple records of type one

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([

{
 $project:{
  detail:{
   $map:{
    input:{$filter:{input:"$detail",as:"d",cond:{$eq:["$$d.type","One"]}}},
    as:"d",
    in:{
     "type" : "$$d.type",
      "name" : "$$d.name",
      "numbers":{$slice:["$$d.numbers",10]}
    }

   }

  }
 }
}

])
```